# Enzyme and Jest using render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

I have a simple application on React and React-router:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export const Home = () => (
  <div className="Home">Home</div>
);

export const Profile = () => (
  <div className="Profile">Profile</div>
);

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/anotherRouteToProfile" component={Profile}/>
  </Switch>
);

export default App;
```

I want to write routing tests like this

```
describe('<App />', () => {
  it('on "/profile" render `Profile` container', () => {
    const wrapper = render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/profile']}>
        <App/>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(
      wrapper.is(Profile)
    ).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Why this test is pass? In the browser on route `/profile` rendred blank page and on route `/anotherRouteToProfile` rendered Profile-component.

[image]

Comment: Please show what profile is on the test, Also chekc if Profile is being correctly imported

Comment: i think all about imports is ok. imgur.com/a/Uun7U http://imgur.com/a/6tvd3

Comment: Instead of using .is can you try to find it and check the length https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.md ? Just to be sure of one stuff